# loop a variable outside the file

Tags: linux, bash, gwas

I will try to explain it. I have a .sh file that do a gwas for each cromosome in bash. This .sh file works but I would like to do a loop to automatize it instead of changing the cromosome (from 1 to 22) each time I do it. **I will put a part of a code as its not mine and idk if I can post it**:

This is an example with chr 21 if I do:

```
#!/bin/bash -f 

# Assuming run by chromosome so   

# set to chromosome.
chr=21

# path to program
program=../programs/program

# path to genotype file
geno=../chr{chr}.1001.bin

# path to program phenotype file 
pheno=../data/pheno.csv
```

Then from bash i do `bash gwas.sh` and it works for 21 chromosome.
This is a part but it works. I tried this:

1. change the file a little bit:

```
#!/bin/bash -f 

# Assuming run by chromosome so   

# set to chromosome.
chr=$CHR

# path to program
program=../programs/program

# path to genotype file
geno=../chr{chr}.1001.bin

# path to program phenotype file 
pheno=../data/pheno.csv
```

And then from bash I did

```
for ((CHR=1; CHR<22; CHR++)); do
echo $CHR

bash gwas.sh

done
```

Thank you so much in advance

**ANSWERD: (Verpous answered it)**

1. change the file:

```
#!/bin/bash -f 

# Assuming run by chromosome so   

# set to chromosome.
export chr=

# path to program
program=../programs/program

# path to genotype file
geno=../chr{chr}.1001.bin

# path to program phenotype file 
pheno=../data/pheno.csv
```

then do:

```
for ((CHR=1; CHR<23; CHR++)); do
export chr=$CHR

bash ../scripts/gwas.sh

done
```

Comment: The variable CHR won't exist from inside the script unless you `export` it. Why not make gwas.sh take it as an argument instead?

Comment: What should it do?  `geno=../chr{chr}.1001.bin` or rather what does it expand to?

Comment: @Jetchisel to make the code work i need to have for chr=1, geno=../chr1.1001.bin ; for chr=2, geno=../chr2.1001.bin . So instead to do it manually, I did it like this. Now what I want to do is a loop that for chr = x take also geno=../chrx.1001.bin and continue to all script. But IDK how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Answered: (Verpous answered it in the comments)

change the file:

```
#!/bin/bash -f 

# Assuming run by chromosome so   

# set to chromosome.
export chr=

# path to program
program=../programs/program

# path to genotype file
geno=../chr{chr}.1001.bin

# path to program phenotype file 
pheno=../data/pheno.csv
```

then do:

```
for ((CHR=1; CHR<23; CHR++)); do
export chr=$CHR

bash ../scripts/gwas.sh

done
```